# Devise Omniauth Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have Devise setup working with my rails app and trying to use Omniauth to add FB login too. I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview . After implementing the codes, when I click on the Devise generated link to login to FB, it takes me to a page to authenticate FB username and password (if I am not logged in to FB in that computer already). After the authentication, the I am redirected to Signup page (the page used for devise email signup). I don't know why the app fails to login/signin to the app. I have looked at other tutorials on this subjects and tried some, but seems like they are outdated. Any help will be much appreciated.

Addition: Looking at the logfile, it seems like my user (which I call "userd") is not getting the email from facebook. Here is part of the logfile, that shows, that userd.email is null:

Userd Load (40.9ms)  SELECT  "userds".* FROM "userds" WHERE "userds"."provider" = ? AND "userds"."uid" = ?  ORDER BY "userds"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "1788392194714140"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Userd Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "userds" WHERE "userds"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (37.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://rails-project-165470.nitrousapp.com/userds/sign_up

Edit: So, I confirmed that problem is only related to facebook returning nil email. If I just hardcode an email address for the facebook user, the login works and facebook does supply the facebook username to be used for my app. I need to figure out how to make FB provide the user email address.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem. It was just that my Omniauth Facebook gem was not updated. Problem solved.

Comment: Hi Tan. I have the same problem and i did update the gem and i still get the same message. Are you sure it was that? Also, what is in your facebook app redirect URIs? Thanks

Comment: Hi Tan, I have faced same issue and i checked my gem version , it is latest, are you sure with the same answer?